# MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/criminals 'gender'

Tags: python, django

I sufering from the problem with my code, whenever i entered my data into the database and then at time when i click submit it will through an error Multyvaluekeyerror. i change my form value so many times but nothing is working. Please help me out this.....it very be thankfull.

```
    MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/criminals
    'gender'
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/criminals
    Django Version: 2.2.4
    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
    Exception Value:    
    'gender'
    Exception Location: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.7.4
    Python Path:    
    ['D:\\django project\\gadmin3',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Mon, 7 Oct 2019 04:35:54 +0000
```

```
MAIN FORM CODE:-
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Gender</label>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div name="gender" id="" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
             <label class="btn btn-default" data-toggle-class="btn-primary" 
                data-toggle-passive-class="btn-default">
             <input type="radio" name="" value="male" data-parsley- 
                multiple="gender"> &nbsp; Male &nbsp;
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle-class="btn-primary" 
                data-toggle-passive-class="btn-default">
             <input type="radio" name="" value="female" data-parsley- 
                multiple="gender"> Female
             </label>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

VIEW SIDE CODE:-

```
    def criminals(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            cn = request.POST['crname']
            ccrime = request.POST['crime']
            cage = request.POST['age']
            cheight=request.POST['height']
            cbody = request.POST['bodymark']
            crgen = request.POST['gender']
            s= Criminals()
            s.mname=cn
            s.mcrime=ccrime
            s.mage=cage
            s.image = request.FILES['photo']
            s.mheight=cheight
            s.mbody=cbody
            s.mgender=crgen
            s.save()
            messages.success(request,"Criminal Added Successfully.")
            return render(request,'criminal.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'criminal.html')
```

Comment: Does this error reproduces with POSTMAN as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs have name in them e.g

```
<input type="radio" name="" value="female" data-parsley-
```

This should be

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" data-parsley-
```

Your code can be futher refactored to:

```
def criminals(request):
             if request.method=="POST":
                    s= Criminals(mname=request.POST['crname'],
                                ccrime=request.POST['crime'], 
                                mage=request.POST['age'],
                                mheight= request.POST['height'],
                                mbody=request.POST['bodymark'], 
                                mgender=request.POST['gender'])
                    s.save()
                    messages.success(request,"Criminal Added Successfully.")
                    return render(request,'criminal.html')
                else:
                    return render(request,'criminal.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

`gender` is a radio type button **(also add the name in your form)** and in case of not selected any option then you will not get any input.

To avoid this issue use the `get` method for extracting the value from `POST` request.

```
crgen = request.POST.get('gender', default_value)
```

This will eliminate the `MultiValueDictKeyError` issue